# Integrate the use of webdriver session ID in Page Object Model

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I would like to run an automated testing in our web application and have run into a bothersome trouble which is runtime of the test cases. In order to optimize that I have decided that it would be best that the browser in the valid test cases should not be rerun from the login page.

I have researched on getting and using session ids, but I do not have an idea on how to integrate it on a POM (Page Object Model)

This is my setup:

`conftest.py`

```
@pytest.fixture()`
def driver(request):
    browser = request.config.getoption("--browser")
    proxy_username = ''
    proxy_password = ''
    
    seleniumwire_options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': f'http://{proxy_username}:{proxy_password}@999.999.999.99:9999',
        'verify_ssl': False,
        },
    }
    if browser == 'edge':
        # browser_driver = webdriver.Edge()
        browser_driver = webdriver.Edge(seleniumwire_options=seleniumwire_options)
    elif browser == 'chrome':
        browser_driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                                          seleniumwire_options=seleniumwire_options)
    elif browser == 'firefox':
        browser_driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
    else:
        raise TypeError(f"{browser} not available")
  
    yield browser_driver

    browser_driver.quit()


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--browser",
        action="store",
        default='edge',
        help='browser to execute test(edge, chrome, or firefox)')
```

`base_page.py`

```
class BasePage:
    def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver):
        self._driver = driver
        self._wait = WebDriverWait(self._driver, timeout=10)

*and other functions*
```

`login_page.py`

```
class LoginPage(BasePage):
    __url = sampleurl

    def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver):
        super().__init__(driver)
```

I am using Python 3.10.